# Eclipse Git (EGit) - How to revert local master back to remote master after a foul merge & commit with a local branch

Tags: eclipse, git, merge

I have the following setup:

- Remote origin/master (default branch)
- Locally, I got the master and created another branch - NewBranch.

Someone in my team updated master on the remote. I was able to pull in all the changes that they made.

However, while merging I had conflicts. Unintentionally, instead of updating **NewBranch** with the conflicted result, I have updated the local master with NewBranch (because master was the one that was currently checked out-or "active" in Eclipse). Furthermore I committed this change (locally) to my local master branch...

I was able to switch to NewBranch and merge it with all the latest changes (so my Newbranch is perfectly the way I want it).

Now, I'd like the master to point to the same version as remote master does. 
So that in the future I have a clean merge between my NewBranch and the Master

I've tried to "Reset" the master, but after performing a hard reset, the Hash Ids b/w the local master and remote master still do not match.

I also have References in my git eclipse and the reference of FETCH_HEAD is the one I'd like my master to revert to.

How can I do this using git in Eclipse?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. Why are you suggesting something that you_dont_want_me_to_try?

Comment: Right - can I do a revert on the entire local master? if so I'll research on how to do that via eclipse git? unless you happen to know the answer :-)

Comment: right thanks for your input!

Comment: did you try git merge --abort

Comment: nope...i am looking for something in relation to eclipse and git...if that exists as an option, i am happy to research and try it out...

Comment: Its pretty annoying that someone downvoted this question without offering an explanation or an answer! ..if any of you have a good suggestion, please do put it forward...Thanks again

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, things become hostile sometimes here. They are also generous, just keep asking :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing you are asking these 2 questions?

> 1. Now, I'd like the master to point to the same version as remote master
>      does

If I'm right follow this, if you master should point to remote master

```
git pull origin master
```

If your **NewBranch** should point to remote master

```
git pull origin NewBranch
```

> 2. I also have References in my git eclipse and the reference of
>      FETCH_HEAD is the one I'd like my master to revert to.

### Please right-click on project in your eclipse--->go to team----> check the git options

[image]

These commands will help you to revert to a specific commit

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard e3f1e37
git push --force origin master
# Then to prove it (it won't print any diff)
git diff master..origin/master
```

### Alternative

Sometimes you may want to undo a whole commit with all changes. Instead of going through all the changes manually, you can simply tell git to revert a commit, which does not even have to be the last one. Reverting a commit means to create a new commit that undoes all changes that were made in the bad commit. Just like above, the bad commit remains there, but it no longer affects the the current master and any future commits on top of it.

```
git revert ~specificCommit
```

But remember this after git revert, if you want to go back, you need to read this [Git revert be careful](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt)
 before you do it.

```
git revert 45ae34 e34526a #created two revert commits

git revert HEAD~2..HEAD #by taking ranges, it will revert last 2 commits

git revert -m 1 <merge_commit_sha> #this basically reverts a merge commit

# To get just one, you could use `rebase -i` to squash them afterwards
# Or, you could do it manually (be sure to do this at top level of the repo)
# get your index and work tree into the desired state, without changing HEAD:
git checkout 34e2w34 .

git commit #commit here
```

Docs:
git docs: [undo merges](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html)